# Designing highly available VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been reading and watching everything [1] I can related to designing highly available VPCs. I have a couple of questions. For a typical 3-tier application (web, app, db) that needs HA within a single region it looks like you need to do the following:

- Create one public subnet in each AZ.
- Create one web, app, and db private subnet in each AZ.
- Ensure your web, app and db EC2 instances are split evenly between AZs (for this post assume the DBs are running hot/hot  and the apps are stateless).
- Use an ALB / autoscaling to distribute load across the web tier. From what I read ALBs provide HA across AZs within the same region.
- Utilize Internet gateways to provide a target route for Internet traffic.
- Use NAT gateways to SRC NAT the private subnet VMs so they can get out to 
  the Internet.

With this approach do you need to deploy one Internet and NAT gateway to each AZ? If you only deploy one what happens when you have an AZ outage. Are these services AZ aware (can't find a good answer for this question). Any and all feedback (glad to RTFM) is welcomed!

Thank you,
- Mick

[1] Last two resources I reviewed

[Deploying production grade VPCs](https://gruntwork.io/guides/networking/how-to-deploy-production-grade-vpc-aws/)

[High Availability Application Architectures in Amazon VPC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fEHhBX7YKE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need NAT Gateway in each AZ as the redundancy is limited to a single AZ. Here is the snippet from the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html)

> Each NAT gateway is created in a specific Availability Zone and
>   implemented with redundancy in that zone.

You need just a single Internet gateway for a VPC as it is redundant across AZs and a VPC level resource. Here is the snippet from [Internet Gateway offical documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html)

> An internet gateway is a horizontally scaled, redundant, and highly
>   available VPC component that allows communication between instances in
>   your VPC and the internet. It therefore imposes no availability risks
>   or bandwidth constraints on your network traffic.

Here is a highly available architecture image showing NAT GW per AZ and Internet GW as a VPC resource

[image]

Image source: https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vpc/

Comment: @juned How would private Subnet B and it's dedicated custom acl be used?

Comment: @RodrigoM you need one private subnet per AZ to handle an AZ failure. Your EC2 instances woudl then be split betweeen those private subnets. With this set up if AZa goes down you will lose access to the instances in AZa. But if you have EC2 instances connected to a private subnet in AZb they will still be available to process incoming requests. Sticking an ALB/NLB (ideally with ASGs) in front of the instances provides automated failover. I think this is what Juned Ahsan was alluding to.